# Why doesn't Ubuntu load after installing via wubi on a RAID 0 setup?

Tags: wubi, raid

I tried to install wubi on my raid 0 (Windows) and it installs correctly but it doesn't load Ubuntu.

No error message, just it's doing nothing when starting to load!

Answer (score 1):

> > **Gonna go ahead and try to answer this, because i know that people who use the Windows installer tend to be new(er) to Linux. 
> >  Also going to answer the "why"**

If i recall correctly (as to say, i may be wrong)

Wubi creates a Disk(virtual)Image "loop" file on your windows partition

> This file is then mounted at boot and Ubuntu pretends its a hard drive

and will then boot into that

- Because the raid is mounted on windows drivers (fakeraid: bios Style) The boot loader will be expecting a standard single drive.
Thus it wont boot.

On the off chance anyone reads and asks this question, I decided to answer it.
To solve it, you would have to program the bootloader to first assemble the raid (I think thats dmraid, ya?) then to mount the loop.

Which im sorry but, I dont remember how to do that.
But im pretty sure you can install Grub to a USB stick and program that to read your RAID0